# Iterate i'th row in vector of vectors

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, iterator

I have a created one 2d array using vector of vectors

```
vector< vector<int> > vvi;
```

I can iterate this whole vector with below iterators:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator row; 
std::vector<int>::iterator col; 

for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); ++row)
{ 
     for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
     { 
        std::cout << *col; 
     } 
}
```

Instead of traversing the whole 2d array, I need to traverse any i'th row like this but it's not working

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator row; 
std::vector<int>::iterator col;
row = vvi[i];
for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        std::cout << *col;          
}
```

How can I solve this problem.Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: `auto & row = vvi[row_index];` and then `row.begin();` etc.

Comment: You are getting an error message, I assume.  Are you having difficulty understanding the message?

Comment: @VTT what's the difference in your code and my code? I think I am doing the same thing.

Comment: @AnandGupta `operator[]` of vector returns a reference to item, not an iterator to item.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes I am getting the error message, how can I solve this problem.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @AnandGupta you need to solve the problem described in the error message.  And if you don't understand the message, show the message to someone and ask what that message means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `row` is an iterator so you can't assign `vvi[i]` to it.
In your situation, this can work:

```
#include <iterator>
// ...
std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator row = vvi.begin();
std::advance(row, i);

for (std::vector<int>::iterator col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
  std::cout << *col << std::endl;
}
```

You could also do something simple like (C++11 below):

```
for (auto const& x : vvi[i]) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

If you wouldn't like to use the range-for syntax, one more alternative solution could be:

```
auto const& row = vvi[i];
for (auto col = row.cbegin(); col != row.cend(); ++col)
{
  std::cout << *col << std::endl;
}
```

Note please, that here I used `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead of `begin()` and `end()`. (If you uncertain about the differences, please do some research about iterators and const_iterators.)

A final remark: I used the increment operator as a prefix (`++col`) in both examples (just like you did in your first one): in your case, there is no need for the overhead that the suffix version provides. (Even this is a subtle performance plus, it's just not necessary.)

Truly hope that I could help.